# If teo subgroups are cyclic, the groups is cyclic?

Tags: cyclic-groups

i've got a group $G$, and its subgroup $L$, L is normal in G. If L and G/L are cyclic, is G  cyclic?

---

I know that in the other direction is true but what about this? i have no idea

Comment: Let $G$ be the  non-cyclic group of order $4$ and let $L$ be a subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: i need the demostration

Comment: Of what?  A single counterexample suffices to disprove a proposed theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Think about S3, order 6, non-abelian.